# strange behavior on c++ string append

Tags: c++, string

I have a strange problem with c++ string object in my class on the line `s.append(ptr2str ....);`

```
class cRegexMatches {
public:
    char *ptr2str;
    int   *pOffsets;
    cRegexMatches() { ptr2str = NULL; pOffsets=NULL;}
    void update(char *p, int *offsets) {
        ptr2str = p; pOffsets = offsets;
        printf("ptr2str=%p %s|\n", p, p);
    }
    string operator [] (int id) {
        string s;
        printf("operator[] %p %s|", ptr2str, ptr2str);
        int i;
        for (i=0; i<4; i++) printf(" %d", pOffsets[i]);
        printf("\n");
        if (!ptr2str) return s;
        if (pOffsets[2 * id + 1] == 0) return s;
        int len = pOffsets[2 * id + 1] - pOffsets[2 * id];
        printf("size %d %ld before %s\n", s.size(), len, ptr2str + pOffsets[2 * id]);
        s.append(ptr2str + pOffsets[2 * id], len);
        cout << s << endl;
        return s;
    }
};
```

It runs fine with the follow code.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *p = "10.20.0.111:8080";
    int pInts[] = {0, 16, 0,16};
    regmatches.update(p, &pInts[0]);
    string s =  regmatches[0];
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<s.size(); i++) {
        printf("%c\n", s.c_str()[i]);
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

But in my project,  the line `s.append(ptr2str + pOffsets[2 * id], len);` seems to corrupt the first byte to be \x00, according to the debug statement `printf(..)` before `s.append` and the `cout ...` afterwards.

Any idea what caused the strange behavior?  Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**

Thanks to @user657267's suggestion,  here is a brief description on how the code was used in my project.  It looks very innocent.

```
cRegexMatches globalVar;

//p points to some c string 
//pInt points to an array of integers, in my case, it's 0,  16, 0, 16
globalVar.update(p, pInt);
cout << globalVar[0]
```

For now, I found a workaround:  I changed the line `s.append(ptr2str + pOffsets[2 * id], len);` to `return string(ptr2str + pOffsets[2 * id], len);` and it worked fine.  But I am still curious on what caused the strange behavior.

Comment: When posting an example you need to post the code that **isn't** working, what use is a working example for?

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you're missing the "complete" part.

Comment: I ran you code and I didn't find any problem.

Comment: @thanks for guys for looking into it!  I will try to find time to get a minimal example that has the problem.   Have to go now.

Comment: this `char *p` should be `const char *p`.  You will get a bunch of errors as a result of that change, any you will need to fix them.  alternatively just use `std::string` everywhere

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem might be your definition of the string in main.

```
char* p = "10.20.0.111:8080";
```

should be

```
char p[] = "10.20.0.111:8080";
```

Only the second definition reserves memory on the stack.